# How to import external vars and functions from external modules?

Tags: xquery

test2.xqy:

```
import module namespace myNS = "http://test.org/module1" at "./namespace.xqy";

element test
{

}
```

namespace.xqy:

```
module namespace myNS = "http://test.org/module1";

declare variable $myNS:srcDoc:="test2.xml";
declare variable $myNS:defaultXMLNS:="http://www.test.com#";
declare variable $myNS:defaultXMLBase:=$defaultXMLNS;
```

Command line:

```
$ basex test2.xqy
Stopped at /Users/jack/Documents/xqy/namespace.xqy, 5/53:
[XPST0008] Undefined variable $defaultXMLNS.
```

I didn't find doc about how to import vars and functions from external modules. So I try it in a intuitive way. The error says there is no definition for `$defaultXMLNS`. I did define it, but with a namespace prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to define the namespace on the right-hand side of the assignment:

```
declare variable $myNS:defaultXMLBase:=$defaultXMLNS;
                                    (:  ^ no namespace defined :)
```

Thus, `$defaultXMLNS` is searched in the default namespace, where it is not registered. Apply the namespace instead:

```
declare variable $myNS:defaultXMLBase:=$myNS:defaultXMLNS;
```

If you do so, you can later access the value like this:

```
import module namespace myNS = "http://test.org/module1" at "./namespace.xqy";

element test
{
  $myNS:srcDoc
}
```